# Power consumption in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: virtualbox, power-management, 14.04

I am using 14.04 in Virtual Box. Each time i switch on the VM, the laptop powers off. The host being Windows 7. It is already over 7-8 times this has happened. Please let me know how to nullify this. 
Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: Maybe, you have given to much amount of RAM to your virtual machine?

Comment: @enedil I have 6gb and I have parted with 2gigs for vm. it is the only vm which runs currently

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with a way to solve this :
here check it up on my blog :)

http://worldofenggcodes.blogspot.in/2014/05/for-all-people-with-power-problems.html

Share the answer if it works :)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: It may not be the absolute answer which will fit the users scenario but i have rollbacked my kernel version and its working,my battery life has increased,itz coz of the kernel,they have mentioned about power management on http://www.kernel.org in the change log of 3.12 kernel